# Wrapping array of C objects into C++ class

Tags: c++, c++11

I have `C` library with such API:

```
extern "C" {
    typedef struct Opaque Opaque;

    Opaque *foo_new();
    void foo_delete(Opaque *);
    int foo_f(Opaque *, int);
}
```

To simplify it's usage I wrap it in such way:

```
class Foo final {
public:
    Foo() { self_ = foo_new(); }
    ~Foo() { foo_delete(self_); }
    //code for copy/move constructor and operator=
    int f(int a) { return foo_f(self_, a); }
private:
    Opaque *self_;
};
```

All great, but then I have to wrap array of this opaque objects:

```
extern "C" {
    typedef struct OpaqueArray OpaqueArray;

    OpaqueArray *calc_foo_array();
    void foo_array_delete(OpaqueArray *);
    Opaque *foo_array_elem(OpaqueArray *, size_t i);
}
```

So I need implement `class FooArray`:

```
class FooArray final {
public:
    ??? operator[](const size_t i) {
       auto obj = foo_array_elem(self_, i);
       ???
    }
private:
    OpaqueArray *self_;
};
```

But what should I return as result of `operator[]`?

I can create `Foo` from `Opaque *`, but then `Foo::~Foo()` is free part of array,
what is wrong. I can create `FooRef` that would be exactly the same as `Foo`,
but do not call `foo_delete`, but actually I have several such `C classes`,
and I prefer do not create so many code duplicates.
May be I can somehow use `reinterpret_cast`, because of `sizeof(Foo) = sizeof(Opaque *)` and return `Foo &` from `operator[]`, but `Foo &` actually is `Opaque **`,
so I need somewhere hold `Opaque` to make it address stable.

May be there is some standard solution for such kind of problem?

Comment: Do you really need `f` to be a member-function? You could simply let `f` be a free-function and have `operator[]` returns a `Opaque*` with `Foo` having an implicit conversion operator to `Opaque*`.

Comment: OT: you are violating the rule of 3/5/0.

Comment: @manni66 If you mean copy/assigment I just skip them, you can find code comment about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it using proposed by You `FooRef` but a bit differently:

```
class FooRef {
public:
    FooRef (Opaque *o) { self_ = o; }
    int f(int a) { return foo_f(self_, a); }
protected:
    Opaque *self_;
};


class Foo : public FooRef {
public:
    Foo() { self_ = foo_new(); }
    //code for copy/move constructor and operator=
    ~Foo () { foo_delete(self_); }
};
```

This solution avoids code duplication and allows you to safely return Foo from array. And by the way you got mechanism to simply create `FooRef` from `Foo`. Now you can do just:

```
class FooArray final {
public:
    FooRef operator[](const size_t i) {
       return FooRef(foo_array_elem(self_, i));
    }
private:
    OpaqueArray *self_;
};
```

I think that this should do the trick in elegant way.

Comment: This could be improved by giving `FooRef` a virtual destructor, so a user can for example store a `std::unique_ptr<FooRef>` that really points at a `Foo`.

Comment: @aschepler Partially true. But on the other hand it adds vtable to the class, which makes you pay for what you don't (or may not) use

Answer (score 4):

You could modify your Foo class so that it can hold a pointer that it doesn't own.

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo()
        {
            self_ = foo_new();
            m_owned = true;
        }

        Foo(Opaque *pOpaque) 
        { 
            self_ = foo_new(); 
            m_owned = false;
        }

        ~Foo()
        {
            if (m_owned) foo_delete(self_);
        }

        //code for copy/move constructor and operator=
        int f(int a) { return foo_f(self_, a); }

    private:
        bool m_owned;
        Opaque *self_;
};


class FooArray
{
    public:
        Foo operator[](const size_t i)
        {
           return Foo(foo_array_elem(self_, i));
        }

    private:
        OpaqueArray *self_;
};
```

Comment: But why runtime decision, while I know at compile time should I call `foo_delete` or not?

Comment: I generally to write code that is not designed for one very specific case.   If other code creates and deletes the entries in the array, then it would be bad for the Foo class to also delete an entry in the array that it is "wrapping".  his way it handles both cases (1) items that it created and (2) items that were created elsewhere.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `_self = pOpaque` in the constructor accepting a `Opaque*`?

Comment: Gian, "self_" is the naming convention that was chosen in the original post, so I kept it.  I would prefer "_self" myself or even (better?) "m_self" (I'm old school) which is what everyone did before someone decided to drop the "m" (m= member).